# Protractor AngularJS mouseOver field to reveal hidden buttons to click

Tags: angularjs, protractor, mouseover

I am new to protractor.  I am trying to hover over a field that will show hidden icons to click on. There is a list of 'Bookings'(Sometimes only 1 sometimes many) that when hovered over reveals a button that will edit or delete that booking.  I am having trouble filtering to the booking I want to hover over the field to reveal delete or edit buttons.

```html
<div class="list-view-container">
  <div class="list-view-header">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 column-item" ng-click="bookingsCtrl.changeBookingSort(bookingsCtrl.sortColumns.postAs)">Booking Name <span class="booking-icon" ng-show="bookingsCtrl.bookingSort === bookingsCtrl.sortColumns.postAs" ng-class="bookingsCtrl.bookingSortReverse? 'icon-down':'icon-up'"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 column-item" ng-click="bookingsCtrl.changeBookingSort(bookingsCtrl.sortColumns.startDate)">Start Date <span class="booking-icon" ng-show="bookingsCtrl.bookingSort === bookingsCtrl.sortColumns.startDate" ng-class="bookingsCtrl.bookingSortReverse? 'icon-down':'icon-up'"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 column-item" ng-click="bookingsCtrl.changeBookingSort(bookingsCtrl.sortColumns.endDate)">End Date <span class="booking-icon" ng-show="bookingsCtrl.bookingSort === bookingsCtrl.sortColumns.endDate" ng-class="bookingsCtrl.bookingSortReverse? 'icon-down':'icon-up'"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 column-item" ng-click="bookingsCtrl.changeBookingSort(bookingsCtrl.sortColumns.ownerName)">Owner <span class="booking-icon" ng-show="bookingsCtrl.bookingSort === bookingsCtrl.sortColumns.ownerName" ng-class="bookingsCtrl.bookingSortReverse? 'icon-down':'icon-up'"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 column-item" ng-click="bookingsCtrl.changeBookingSort(bookingsCtrl.sortColumns.bookingStatus)">Status <span class="booking-icon" ng-show="bookingsCtrl.bookingSort === bookingsCtrl.sortColumns.bookingStatus" ng-class="bookingsCtrl.bookingSortReverse? 'icon-down':'icon-up'"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 column-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item-row" ng-repeat="booking in bookingsCtrl.bookings track by booking.bookingId" ng-click="bookingsCtrl.selectBooking(booking)">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="list-item-name" ng-bind="booking.postAs"></div>
      <div ng-if="bookingsCtrl.isMultipleVenues" ng-bind="bookingsCtrl.getVenueName(booking)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 list-item" ng-bind="booking.startDate | date: 'shortDate'"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 list-item" ng-bind="booking.endDate | date: 'shortDate'"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 list-item" ng-bind="bookingsCtrl.ownerName(booking)"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 list-item" ng-bind="bookingsCtrl.statuses[booking.bookingStatus]"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 list-icon-container">
      <div class="list-icon" ng-click="bookingsCtrl.deleteBooking(booking.bookingId)" stop-event>
        <span class="booking-icon icon-delete"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="list-icon" ng-click="bookingsCtrl.editBooking(booking.bookingId)" stop-event>
        <span class="booking-icon icon-gear"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Below is what I have and I believe I am way off. I have the booking name itself set to elementText however it is stored in the database with a unique id. Any help would be great.

```js
if (elementText == bookingName1) {
  console.log('Found booking: ' + elementText);
  //bookingToEdit = bookingList.get(i);
  var list - element = element.all(by.click('bookingsCtrl.selectBooking(bookingName1)')).first();
  browser.actions().mouseMove(list - element).perform();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, this is a use case for [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
var desiredBooking = element.all(by.exactRepeater("booking in bookingsCtrl.bookings")).filter(function (booking) {
    return booking.evaluate("booking.postAs").then(function (bookingName) {
        return bookingName === desiredBookingName;
    });
}).first();

// delete it
desiredBooking.element(by.css("div[ng-click*=deleteBooking]")).click();
```

Assuming `booking.postAs` is a booking name.